# What does the red part of the health bar mean on an exploring dweller?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I've sent a dweller out to explore. He's carrying a gun and an outfit and ten stimpacks as well as one radaway. After some time he lost some health. Part of the green bar is gone, but there is now also a bit of red on the right hand side of the health bar. He has not used any of the consumables.

**What does the red part of the health bar mean, and will it go away?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The red part of the bar means that he has become irradiated, which lowers his max-health. If he has Radaway with him, he will use it once a certain threshold has been reached.

If he has no Radaway and his irradiation gets worse, you should call him back. While dwellers are on their way back to the vault, they don't take any damage.

The irradiation will go away slowly, once he is back in the vault **and** you have enough clean water. If you don't have clean water, your dwellers will start to get irradiated slowly.

Comment: That makes sense. It also answered another question I had in my head. I wasn't sure if he would use his consumables automatically.

Comment: They do, so if leaving explorers to... well... explore... for a lengthy period of time, its a good idea to provide plenty of staying power. I have recently taken to sending 4 dwellers out each with 8 stimpacks and 5 radaways, despite it being complete overkill. I currently have 60 dwellers